# How to have the root cause of a BadRequestError during azure function deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a new version of an already existing Azure Function using the cli using the following command:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g "resourcegroupeok" -n "function-app" --src MyNewFunction.zip
```

But I only get an error:
`BadRequestError: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Bad Request'`

Is there a way to increase verbosity or to have more infos on what to check?

***MyNewFunction.zip*** contains a ***JAR*** and a ***host.json*** file.

NB: When I try to put a wrong resourge group name of a wrong function app name, I have a precise error telling me to check theses values.

Example:

```
The function app 'Bad-Function-App' was not found in resource group 'resourcegroupeok'. Please make sure these values are correct.
```

Comment: Can you try getting output wiht --debug flag on your command? Perhaps it will give more insight. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/get-started-with-azure-cli#globally-available-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment by @Marco, the correct option is `--debug`